# wordpress shortcodes show up in preview posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

http://www.mytwins.gr/site/

In the third blog post you will see that a shortcode shows up `[frame align="none"]Της Εύης Σταθάτου[/frame]`  which is ugly. Only if you click it, it works fine.

Why is that?, How can you hide the code from the previews posts thingy? Thanks in advance.

P.S I tried to hide the shortcode from the visual mode and enter it in the text mode, but still the same.

Comment: Please check you plugin is active or deactivate ? if your plugin is deactivate at that time it's happened.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ravi suggests, make sure that your plugins are enabled. However, it looks like your shortcodes are appearing within your excerpts (assuming you're using `the_excerpt()` for the snippets appearing on your homepage?)

I would suggest a handy snippet of RegEx:

```
$myExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$myExcerpt = preg_replace( '|\[(.+?)\](.+?\[/\\1\])?|s', '', $myExcerpt);
echo $myExcerpt;
```

That should stop the raw shortcodes from appearing.